# Distributing balls on boxes

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to distribute 3 balls on 4 boxes ?
My turn :
The number of ways is $$C^{n+r-1}_r =C^{4+3-1}_3 = 20 $$
Is the solution correct ?

Comment: Balls and/or boxes are distinguishable?

Comment: The boxs are distinguishable but the balls are not @callculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or....

If all three balls are in the same box, there are $4$ such ways.

If two balls are in one box, and one in another, there are $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ ways.

If there is one ball per box, there are $4$ such ways (determined by the sole empty box).

$4 + 12 + 4 = 20$